# Does gradient descent work for tabular Q learning?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, q-learning

Suppose I have a tabular Q learning problem such as grid-world.

Let our loss be defined as,

$$\hat{L}(Q)=0.5(Q(s,a)-(r+\gamma\max_{a'}{Q(s',a')}))^2$$

Then $Q_{k+1}(s,a) = Q_k(s,a) - \eta \nabla \hat {L}(Q) = Q_k(s,a) - \eta(Q_k(s,a) - r_k+\gamma\max_{a'}{Q_k(s',a')})$ which is just Q learning.

So, does a gradient descent approach make sense if we take our loss function to be the difference between the current Q value and the TD error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible; you are close, but not quite there.

You lost a gradient in your equation; it should be:
$$Q_{k+1}(s,a) = Q_k(s,a) - \eta \left(Q(s,a)-(r+\gamma\max_{a'}{Q(s',a')})\right)\left(\left.\frac{d~Q}{d~\theta}\right|_{(s,a)} - \gamma \left.\frac{d~\max_{a'}Q}{d~\theta}\right|_{(s')} \right)$$

Which does simplify a bit in the case of a tabular representation:

$$Q_{k+1}(s,a) = Q_k(s,a) - \eta \left(Q(s,a)-(r+\gamma\max_{a'}{Q(s',a')})\right)\left(1 - \gamma \left.\frac{d~\max_{a'}Q}{d~\theta}\right|_{(s')} \right)$$

Problems may arise if $s=s'$ and $a=a'$, because your update will be $0$ (which it shouldn't). It's also not a good idea to try and differentiate the $\max$ function.

You can do the "double deep q-learning trick" and introduce $\theta_\textrm{old}$ to estimate $Q(s',a')$, i.e., use the q-table from the previous step. This will make the other gradient dissapear, and you are indeed left with q-learning:

$$Q_{k+1}(s,a) = Q_k(s,a) - \eta \left(Q(s,a, \theta)-(r+\gamma\max_{a'}{Q(s',a', \theta_\textrm{old})})\right)$$

In this case, the loss will be

$$\hat L(\theta)= \frac12 \left(Q(s,a,\theta)−(r+\gamma \max_{a′}Q(s′,a′, \theta_\textrm{old}))\right)^2$$